# Match the 'x' which has even number of 'G' before it

Tags: php, regex

How can I match the 'x' which has even number of 'G' before it?

For example:

```
x       --> Match the 'x'
Gx      --> Match nothing
GGx     --> Match the 'x'
GGGx    --> Match nothing
GGGGx   --> Match the 'x'
...
```

Here I try to use "Nagative Look Behind":

```
(?<!G(GG)*)x
```

But the `*` quantifier inside the lookbehind makes it non-fixed width, so this pattern is wrong.

So how can I do?

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: @blhsing I use PHP.

Comment: [`\b(?:G{2})*\Kx`](https://regex101.com/r/cp9vqS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex,

```
\b(?:[Gg]{2})*\K[xX]\b
```

Here `\b` ensures the word does not partially match and `(?:[Gg]{2})*` ensures only even number of `G` preceding `x` are matched and `\K` match reset operator ensures only `x` is matched and not the whole string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgklHI/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
(?<!G)(GG)*(?!G)(x)
```

The `x` will be in group 2. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SL2G7I/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `(?<!G(GG)*)x` where the quantifier is in the lookbehind, you can move the `(GG)` out of the lookbehind and turn it into a non capturing group and repeat that 0+ times`(?:GG)*`

Instead if asserting that what is on the left is not a `G`, you could assert that it is not a non-whitespace character using `\S` because `(?<!G)` means that an "a" is valid and will match the x in `ax`

Finally use `\K` to forget what was matched and match an x

```
(?<!\S)(?:GG)*\Kx
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hGTNU/1)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(^|[^G](G{2})+)(x)
```

Match group 3 should give you the x